# Помогите с построением логики скрипта

Tags: javascript, node.js

Пишу бота телеграм, скрипт парсит json и возвращает данные, но т.к json немного кривой, приходится парсить разными запросами.
Есть 2 куска кода:

// FOR RKT   и    // FOR WAVES

Если использовать их по отдельности - все работает, если вместе - нет.

Как сделать проверку на то, какая кнопка нажимается в боте и что именно передается в callback_data, и в зависимости от этого вызвать и обработать нужный кусок кода?

Буду очень признателен, кто сможет помочь

```
bot.onText(/\/price/, (msg, match) => {

  const chatId = msg.chat.id;

    bot.sendMessage(chatId, 'Выберите монету', {
        reply_markup: {
            inline_keyboard: [
                [
                    {
                        text: 'RKT8',
                        callback_data: 'rkt8'
                    }, {
                        text: 'WAVES',
                        callback_data: 'WAVES/USD'
                    }
                ]
            ]
        }
    });
});



// FOR RKT
bot.on('callback_query', query => {
    const id = query.message.chat.id;

    request('https://marketdata.wavesplatform.com/api/markets', function(error, response, body) {
        const data = JSON.parse(body);
        const result = data.filter(item => item.amountAssetName === query.data)[1];
        let md = `
            * ${result.amountAssetName.toUpperCase()}/${result.priceAssetID} *
            Покупка: _${result['24h_high']}_
            Продажа: _${result['24h_low']}_
        `;
        bot.sendMessage(id, md, {parse_mode: 'Markdown'});
    })
})

// FOR WAVES
bot.on('callback_query', query => {
    const id = query.message.chat.id;

    request('https://marketdata.wavesplatform.com/api/markets', function(error, response, body) {
        const data = JSON.parse(body);
        const result= data.filter(item => item.symbol === query.data)[0];
        let md = `
            * ${result.symbol} *
            Покупка: _${result['24h_high']}_
            Продажа: _${result['24h_low']}_
        `;
        bot.sendMessage(id, md, {parse_mode: 'Markdown'});
    })
})
```

Comment: И вы конечно хотите быстрый способ, как из двух кривых json'ов сделать стабильно работающее ПО, а не разбираться, в чём кривизна json'а и пытаться её исправить?

Comment: Нет возможности повлиять на json, это выдача биржи

Comment: [JSON](https://marketdata.wavesplatform.com/api/markets) а что в данном JSON кривого??? Если не секрет

Comment: Вам нужна одна функция `callback_query`, в `query.data` будет то, что лежит в `callback_data`.